# Setting a breakpoint in DLL GDB Windows

Tags: c, windows, gcc, gdb

I'm creating a DLL using GCC (cygwin, mingw). Everything works fine, except I want to use gdb to inspect the DLL and set breakpoints where needed while the programming is running.

Is this possible?

Currently I have a simple batch file that builds the project:

```
gcc -c -o jrt.o jrt.c -D DLL_EXPORT
gcc -o jrt.dll jrt.o -g -s -shared -Wl,--subsystem,windows
gcc -o jrt-client jrt-client.c -L./ -ljrt -g
```

I load gdb with `jrt-client.exe` and run `list`. I can see the code from `jrt-client.c`. If I set a breakpoint I can see the DLL is loaded using `i sh`:

```
0x668c1000  0x668ca130  Yes (*)     F:\C\DLL\jrt.dll
```

But from here I don't know how to set a breakpoint within the DLL or if it's even possible.